# django, embedded url, xsendfile, video embed

Tags: iphone, django, video, x-sendfile

I am in the process of building a web app with django.
The app is running on apache and files/videos are served with the xsendfile apache module.
The app is working fine on iphones, ipads and macs on the local network - when I access the site via a url like https://myapp.local

When I visit the app through it's real world domain (https://myapp.com) via a computer everything is ok too.
But when on the iPhone/ipad the videos do not get loaded. The custom url I have made for serving the videos isn't even called.

I am embedding the videos like this:

So the url is called to grab that asset and return the file response with the path.
This 'serveAsset' doesn't get called from the iPhone/iPad.
When I hit that url directly the video doesn't load either.
(But it does from a mac and safari - including using the "Safari iOS7 - iPhone" User agent.

Does Safari iOS7 not work with urls that serve material for the page?

Any ideas what might be going on?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Cheers

Adam

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that the assets were not being served when I was using SSL certification (or accessing the site with https).
With http:// the assets are served.
Now to work out how to get it all working with SSL and django